# Why props.notes.map is not a function? React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to do a map for every note that I receive. So, I have this container that get the data from firebase.

```
db.collection("notes")
      .where("author.email", "==", this.props.authorEmail)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(note => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes: note.data() });
        });
        //this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes: querySnapshot });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("An error was happend :" + error);
      });
```

It's on the componentDidMount. But when I try to map that data for render a component for every note I get the error. `props.notes.map` is not a function

See my component that use `props.notes.map`

```
const MyNotes = props => {
  return (
    <div id="my-notes" className="marged-content">
      <h2>I'm your notes</h2>
      <div id="notes" className="p-grid">
        {props.notes.map(note => {
          return <NoteComponent note={note} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And that's the data that I get in my `MyNotes`component.

```
Object
    notes:
    author: {avatar: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cardon…=media&token=36760a94-84f7-4247-9c22-9d861150e921", email: "jonatanpc.2014@gmail.com", name: "Diego Cardona"}
    content: "<p>sxdd</p>"
    private: false
    title: "A"
```

I get a object for every note in my firebase storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is, that your state (notes) is actually not an array, but an object.

```
db.collection("notes")
.where("author.email", "==", this.props.authorEmail)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const notes = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(note => {
          notes.push(note.data());
        });
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("An error was happend :" + error);
      });
```

in order to get an array out of your db query.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm getting a array!

Comment: And now you should be able to map over it like you wanted to. :)

Comment: Hmm bro, Why am I getting the error using this? `props.notes.map(note => {
          return <NoteComponent note={note} />;
        })`

Comment: What error do you get exactly?
How do you transfer the notes to your MyNotes component?

Can you log what your props.notes is currently look like in MyNotes?

Comment: Thanks bro, I have fixed it :3